# passing parameters to stored procedure entity framework with sql server 2005

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stored proc which takes a int as parameter.  I am using entity framework code first along with MVC and I am making the call in this manner

```
        SqlParameter sa = new SqlParameter("@userId", userId);
        var query = from dashboardData in TBSCIDBContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyNomination>("sp_GetMyNominationList @userId", sa)
                    select dashboardData;
        return query.ToList();
```

in profiler I get

```
exec sp_executesql N'sp_GetMyNominationList @userId',N'@userId int',@userId=4
```

This executes correctly on using sql server 2008 but now my db is changed to 2005
and the same exec statement gives me

Incorrect syntax near 'sp_GetMyNominationList'. because I am running it in 2005.

I have to use 2005 please tell me a way to make this run in 2005 so that the parameter is taken correctly by the sql profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is

```
  SqlParameter sa = new SqlParameter("@userId", userId);
            var query = from dashboardData in TBSCIDBContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyNomination>("exec sp_GetMyNominationList @userId=@userId", sa)
                        select dashboardData;
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

You should be using EntityFramework to [map your stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx). Currently you're just circumventing the whole point of EF, which is to provide a layer between your code and your database. EntityFramework will create a method call with the stored procedure name, which takes the parameters that the stored procedure needs.